# Having two separate grub configs

Tags: grub

so i have two disks: one ssd which is my main system, and a backup one on a usb stick. i want my stick to be bootable: i've changed the fstab and i installed grub. but the grub config on the usb always points to the ssd, which prevents it from booting without the ssd. i edited the /etc/grub.d/40_custom to point to the linux image on the usb and the usb now boots alone, but i find that workaround ugly. how should i configure grub to make both installs independent?

edit: i chrooted to my usb, and launched an update-grub there. it complained about /dev missing.

edit2: i can now bind mount properly /dev, /proc and /sys, chroot and successfully run an isolated `grub-update`, but i can't keep thinking that a second config would be way cleaner.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? UEFI only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi if directly booting an external drive. An "ubuntu" entry is for internal drives and uses configfile to load grub.cfg in an install which can be on an external drive. But then you must always have that external plugged in.  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred i'm sorry i don't understand how your comment has anything to do with my question: i don't use ubuntu and i don't think my grub needs to be repaired

Comment: Grub2 is mostly standard across all Linux distributions. You say you are booting with grub, so do not understand your issue then. While I primarily use Ubuntu or flavors of Ubuntu, I have installed Debian & Fedora just to see how their grub works. There entry is at /EFI/grub not /EFI/ubuntu but otherwise the same.

Comment: @oldfred if i open the grub.conf of my usb i have this line `linux /boot/vmlinuz-XXX root=UUID=my_ssd ro quiet` so it cannot boot without the ssd. that's why i edited 40_custom and now it boots without the ssd. i just want a cleaner method to achieve this, like not having to edit 40_custom everytime i install a new kernel. and i want to do it manually.

Comment: I use labels with link to current kernel, or  use configfile into that other  install's grub. See 6.5 on configfile details
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config
Use labels and configfile to boot another install , Ubuntu adds a link to most current kernel, so we can boot that. Not sure if your system does or not.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359 &
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

Comment: @oldfred i don't want multiple systems appearing on grub, i want two configs for grub: when i boot from my ssd i don't want to hear about my usb and when i boot from my usb i don't want to hear from my ssd. two clean separate grub installs on each

Comment: I turn off os-prober, so only default entry & those that I add into 40_custom appear. If using UEFI, you need an ESP - efi system partition on external drive. Ubuntu will only install to ESP on internal drive, so I have to manually reconfigure. Both Debian & Fedora let me install to ESP on second drive. Do you have ESP on USB drive? And then boot that directly from UEFI boot menu? UEFI default boots USB drives from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, just like a USB installer any other distribution or even Windows, just different bootx64.efi files.

Answer (score 0):

from what i've learned i think it's not possible. the `grub-mkconfig` is not too complicated to read, but it calls `grub-probe` which is a binary and that's why `grub-mkconfig` only produces grub entries pointing to the "actual host" (not sure of the terminology here)